# Project the elements of an inner dictionary on the root level in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongo Structure like this:

```
'Hash'  : 10111
'Offer' : {
        'valid' : True,
        'title' : BOGO
        'domain': amazon.com
       }
```

And I want the result of the Mongo Query to be something like:

```
'valid' : True,
'title' : BOGO
'domain': amazon.com
```

Not nested inside the offer field.

```
'Offer' : {
        'valid' : True,
        'title' : BOGO
        'domain': amazon.com
       }
```

Can this be done?

Comment: `collection.aggregate([{'$project': {'valid': '$Offer.valid', 'title': '$Offer.title', 'domain': '$Offer.domain'}}])`

Comment: Is there any way this can be generalized? I have close to 30 fields in my offer dictionary which I want to project. Thanks!

Comment: No you can't do that?

Comment: @user3100115 Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @FrancisEytanDortort statement:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb's replaceroot command. It is supported from mongo version 3.4+

```
db.produce.aggregate( [
   {
     $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$Offer" }
   }
] )
```